# Random Number Generation without repetition in Java

Tags: java, cryptography

I would like to get clarifications on Pseudo Random Number generation.
My questions are:

- Is there any chance for getting repeated numbers in Pseudo Random Number Generation?
- When i googled i found true random number generation. Can i get some algorithms for true random number generation, so that i can use it with

  > SecureRandom.getInstance(String algorithm)

Please give guidance with priority given to security.

Comment: http://www.random.org/randomness/ is a good introduction to the philosophy behind random generators. Summary: Algorithms will after some (long) time will inevitably repeat themselves. True random generators need some external source based on some physical observation (toin coss, atmospheric noise, etc.)

Comment: @Thilo Can u please mention some algorithms for achieving true random number generation, any if exists?

Comment: @Maximin True randomness is only obtainable from a source of natural randomness, such as a noisy diode or something based on radioactive decay. Only specialised hardware can produce such values. All other efforts to produce randomness are pseudo random number generators (PRNGs), which don't provide "true" random numbers. However, they are pretty good for most uses. Even hardware security modules use PRNGs (albeit seeded by a true random source).

Comment: @DuncanJones Thank you. Cleared my doubt.

Comment: Note that "random" is an ill-defined term. Given a source of data there is no definite procedure to confirm that the source is "truly random".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes, you can generally have repeated numbers in a PRNG. Actually, if you apply the pigeon hole principle, the proof is quite straightforward (ie, suppose you have a PRNG on the set of 32-bit unsigned integers; if you generate more than 2^32 pseudo random numbers, you will certainly have at least one number generated at least 2 times; in practice, that would happen way faster; usually the algorithms for PRNGs will cycle through a sequence, and you have a way to calculate or estimate the size of that cycle, at the end of which every single number will start repeating, and the image of the algorithm is usually way, *way* smaller than the set from which you take your numbers).

If you need non-repeated numbers (since security seems to be a concern for you, note that this is *less secure* than a sequence of (pseudo) random numbers in which you allow repeated numbers!!!), you can do as follows:

```
class NonRepeatedPRNG {
  private final Random rnd = new Random();
  private final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
  public int nextInt() {
    for (;;) {
      final int r = rnd.nextInt();
      if (set.add(r)) return r;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the `nextInt` method defined above may never return! Use with caution.

2) No, there's no such thing as an "algorithm for true random number generation", since an algorithm is something known, that you control and can predict (ie, just run it and you have the output; you know exactly its output the next time you run it with the same initial conditions), while a true RNG is completely unpredictable by definition.

For most common non security-related applications (ie, scientific calculations, games, etc), a PRNG will suffice. If security is a concern (ie, you want random numbers for crypto), then a CSPRNG (cryptographycally secure PRNG) will suffice.

If you have an application that cannot work without true randomness, I'm really curious to know more about it.

Comment: Thank you Bruno Reis. If i set the limit of PNRG to get numbers between 1 to 255, repetition will occur only after every number in the range has been chosen randomly, isn't it?

Comment: You mean, using the code I presented above? That code will *never* allow a repetition. And note that it is completely insecure, probably even if you use a CSPRNG (ie, SecureRandom instead of Random). And if you change it a bit to limit it to the range [1, 255] (just change the call to `rnd.nextInt()`), and you call it 256 times **you will necessarily freeze your program**, since the calculation cannot ever return (I'm confident that it will reach this condition way before 256 calls). You have to kill the program, or pull the computer's power cord, to stop it.

Comment: Also it's been appreciated to use SecureRandom than using Random in Math while security is your major concern.

Comment: I am not asking on the basis of the presented code, asking on the basis of theoretical concepts

Comment: Theoretical concepts: let R be a PRNG which is supposed to generate integers between 1 and 255. It is allowed for R to generate *any* sequence, such as (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1). In other words: the definition of a generic PRNG has *nothing* stating *how* are the numbers that it will produce, no rules on the sequence. If you are talking about a CSPRNG, then the only difference is that no one can have non-negligible probability of stating that the sequence came from a CSPRNG rather than a TRNG -- it doesn't say anything about repetitions.

Comment: I really suggest you to take Coursera's course called "Cryptography 1" by professor Dan Boneh, Stanford. It discusses a lot about randomness, PRNG, CSPRNG, their definitions, etc. The course is not easy, you really have to study to understand all the concepts, but if you do, you will have some solid basic knowledge on crypto.

Comment: Maybe one last word of caution: Developing secure algorithms (in a cryptoraphic sense) has a lot of potential pitfalls. Using the wrong algorithms is just one of them. Thus, if you are aiming to develop something that *has* to be secure, get yourself a specialist on this field - or study long enough to be the specialist yourself. This however, might be a long, hard journey.

Comment: In practice you'll get collisions after approximately sqrt(n) numbers when there are a total of n different numbers. See "Birthday problem"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, any random number generator can repeat.  There are three general solutions to the non-duplicate random number problem:

- If you want a few numbers from a large range then pick one and reject
  it if it is a duplicate. If the range is large, then this won't cause
  too many repeated attempts.
- If you want a lot of numbers from a small range, then set out all the numbers in an
  array and shuffle the array. The [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm is standard for array
  shuffling. Take the random numbers in sequence from the shuffled array.
- If you want a lot of numbers from a large range then use an appropriately sized
  encryption algorithm. E.g. for 64 bit numbers use DES and encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 
  in sequence. The output is guaranteed unique because encryption is reversible.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo RNGs can repeat themselves, but True RNGs can also repeat themselves - if they never repeated themselves they wouldn't be random.

A good PRNG once seeded with some (~128 bit) real entropy is practically indistinguishable from a true RNG. You certainly won't get noticeably more collisions or repetitions than with a true RNG.

Therefore you are unlikely to ever need a true random number generator, but if you do check out the HTTP API at [random.org](http://www.random.org/clients/http/). Their API is backed by a true random source. The randomness comes from atmospheric noise.

Comment: True RNGs can also repeat themselves.  A PRNG may have a regular pattern of repetitions while a TRNG will not.  If you get 257 bytes from a TRNG then you will have at least one repeated byte.

Comment: A good PRNG once seeded with some(~128 bit) real entropy is practically indistinguishable from a true RNG. You certainly won't get noticeably more collisions or repetitions than with a true PRNG. `random.org` is a nice way to generate random numbers as a non technical user, but it's completely useless to programmers.

Comment: Good points. It's maybe not *completely* useless for programmers though; the api provided the basis for a [tutorial](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/your-first-message-discovering-akka.html) that helped me get to grips with Akka :)

Answer (score 0):

If a PRNG or RNG never repeated numbers, it would be... really predictable, actually! Imagine a PRNG over the numbers 1 to 8. You see it print out 2, 5, 7, 3, 8, 4, 6. If the PRNG tried its hardest not to repeat itself, now you know the next number is going to be 1 - that's not random at all anymore!

So PRNGs and RNGs produce random output with repetition by default. If you don't want repetition, you should use a shuffling algorithm like the Fisher-Yates Shuffle ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle ) to randomly shuffle an array of the numbers you want, in random order.

Also, if you need a source of random number generation for cryptographic purposes, seek out a provider of cryptographic PRNGs for your language. As long as it's cryptographically strong it should be fine - A true RNG is a lot more expensive (or demands latency, such as using random.org) and not usually needed.